# this fault was caused by a dereference of a high value address

Tags: c, error-handling, address-sanitizer

So I'm getting this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYY71.jpg)

the following is my code segment:

```
void virtual_info(void * heapstart) {

    printf("info is called with heapstart %p\n", heapstart);

    struct node *block = heapstart;

    printf("block memory: %zu block address: %p\n", block->memory, block);
    
    while(block){

        if(block->is_free == true){
            printf("free %zu\n", block->memory);
        }
        else if(block->is_free != true){
            printf("allocated %zu\n", block->memory);
        }

        if(block->leftChild != NULL){

            if(block->leftChild->is_free){                          //line 224
                printf("free %zu\n", block->leftChild->memory);
            }
            else if(block->leftChild->is_free != true){
                printf("allocated %zu\n", block->leftChild->memory);
            }

        }

        if(block->rightChild != NULL){

            if(block->rightChild->is_free){
                printf("free %zu\n", block->rightChild->memory);
            }
            else if(block->rightChild->is_free != true){
                printf("allocated %zu\n", block->rightChild->memory);
            }

        }

        block = block->leftChild;

    }

}
```

In the error message, it says there's something wrong with line 224. I've looked at the logic and can't find anything. Perhaps a much better programmer can help me out here?

Comment: It means that `block` or `block->leftChild` contains a garbage value. Probably you did not set it to null after malloc (or you overwrote it somewhere else).

Comment: Maybe you free 'block' or 'block->leftChild' somewhere else, but dont set it to NULL. Now the pointer is invalid. Maybe you write garbage data to it at some point. Hard to tell with only that little bit of the code. Also you should type out the error instead of linking to a screenshot.

Comment: The error report says "see register values below" and you've omitted them. There is a reason they are printed (but you would also need to show disassembly of the code at crash address).